# Can't put Dropdownlist into a Datagrid

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio, drop-down-menu, datagrid

Right now I have a Datagrid displaying some details for trailers. I want to put a DropDownList into the Datagrid so the location can be changed but I keep getting the error:

> Error    32  Literal content ('') is not allowed
>   within a
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridColumnCollection'. C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\test\lookups\Trailer.aspx   215

I've seen code examples of of DropDownLists in datagrids before so why am I getting this error?
Here's the code for the DataGrid:

```
      <asp:DataGrid runat="server" CssClass="tblResults" OnItemDataBound="dgList_ItemCreated" AllowSorting="true" OnSortCommand="dgTrailer_Sort" ID="dgTrailers" DataKeyField="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblResultsHeader" />
                <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="TrailerMake" HeaderText="Trailer Make" SortExpression="TrailerMake"></asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="TrailerLocation" HeaderText="Trailer Location" SortExpression="TrailerLocation"></asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Year" HeaderText="Year" SortExpression="Year"></asp:BoundColumn>
```

Comment: You are missing `</Columns>`

Comment: sorry that line is in the code I must have missed it when copying it over

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it looks like you are missing the closing tag for Columns.

Secondly, to add a dropdownlist you would have to use asp:TemplateColumn then bind your data to that dropdownlist:

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" CssClass="tblResults" OnItemDataBound="dgList_ItemCreated" AllowSorting="true" OnSortCommand="dgTrailer_Sort" ID="dgTrailers" DataKeyField="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblResultsHeader" />
            <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="TrailerMake" HeaderText="Trailer Make" SortExpression="TrailerMake"></asp:BoundColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="TrailerLocation" HeaderText="Trailer Location" SortExpression="TrailerLocation"></asp:BoundColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Year" HeaderText="Year" SortExpression="Year"></asp:BoundColumn>
                <asp:TemplateColumn><ItemTemplate><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlList" runat="server" /></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateColumn>
            </Columns>
        </asp:DataGrid>
```

Comment: ok thanks I don't have an error anymore. So I set the id to ddlTrailerLocation. I am already using this dropdownlist in another part of the code. But the dropdownlist is still not displaying in the datagrid. Also do I still need the line `<asp:BoundColumn DataField="TrailerLocation" HeaderText="Trailer Location" SortExpression="TrailerLocation"></asp:BoundColumn>` or can it be removed?

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to convert the column to a template, then you can add a dropdownlist into this template and bind your data to the dropdownlist. in the end the column with the dropdown will look like the one below.

```
<Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField>                 
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="32px" Width="178px">
        </asp:DropDownList>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>             
 </Columns>
```

Comment: `<asp:TemplateField>` causes the same error I was getting before